# R : Function doesn't work when I change the parameters order

Tags: r, function

I'm using the `nls.lm` function from the `minpack.lm` package and something "weird" happens when I change the order of the parameters in the residual function

**This code works :**

```
install.packages('minpack.lm')
library(minpack.lm)
## values over which to simulate data
x <- seq(0,100,length=100)
## model based on a list of parameters
getPrediction <- function(parameters, x) 
  parameters$A*exp(-parameters$alpha*x) + parameters$B*exp(-parameters$beta*x) 
## parameter values used to simulate data
pp <- list(A = 2, B = 0.8, alpha = 0.6, beta = 0.01)
## simulated data, with noise
simDNoisy <- getPrediction(pp,x) + rnorm(length(x),sd=.01)
#simDNoisy[seq(1,10)] = rep(10,11)
simDNoisy[1] = 4
## plot data
plot(x,simDNoisy, main="data")

## residual function
residFun <- function(parameters, observed, xx)
  sqrt(abs(observed - getPrediction(parameters, xx)))

## starting values for parameters
parStart <- list(Ar = 3, Br = 2, alphar = 1, betar = 0.05)

## perform fit
rm(nls.out)
nls.out <- nls.lm(par=parStart, 
                  fn = residFun, 
                  observed = simDNoisy,
                  xx = x, 
                  control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1))
nls.out
```

It doesn't work if I replace the residual function by this *(just change parameters order)*

```
residFun <- function(xx, parameters, observed )
  sqrt(abs(observed - getPrediction(xx, parameters)))
```

> Error in parameters$A : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

**Why does it cause this error ?**

Comment: function `getPrediction` expects `parameters` as its first argument and `x` as its second. Invert the arguments there, or try to set them explicitly: `sqrt(abs(observed - getPrediction(x=xx, parameters=parameters)))`.

Comment: My bad I thought I only changed the order in residFunm I don't know why I changed the order in getPrediction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters should match the order of the parameters as defined in the function. The only exception you should use is if you explicitly name them out of order. Consider this example of what the function thinks are two parameters

```
theParameters=function(X,Y){
  print(paste("I think X is",X))
  print(paste("I think Y is",Y))
}

theParameters(X=2,Y=10)
theParameters(Y=10,X=2)
 #you can change the parameter order if you identify them with parameter=...


#but if you don't, it assumes it's in the order of how the function is defined.
# which of these is X and which is Y?
theParameters(10,2)
```

It's preferable to always identify the parameters, but *nececessary* if it's out of order. (Other languages don't even let you change the order of parameters when you call them).

```
  getPrediction(xx=xx,parameters=parameters)
```

In this case the reason is the function treats xx and parameters as if it had created its own local copy. Without the identification this line

```
  getPrediction(xx,parameters)
```

means this to R

```
  getPrediction(parameters=xx,xx=parameters)
```

because that matches the original signature of the function.

So the function's version of `parameters` is what you pass in as `xx`, and so on.

Because you called the parameters the same thing as variable names, it can be confusing. It works easier if you vary the dummy version of variable names slightly. Alternatively if scopes of variables allow it, you don't even have to  pass in the parameters, but be careful with that practice because it can cause tracing headaches.